# sacar valor mínimo y mostrar varias filas mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

tengo un problema en una consulta mysql quiero sacar el valor mínimo del campo idenvio ej pero al momento de definir el MIN solo me muestra la 1 fila sola.

MYSQL

```
SELECT MIN(idenvio),nombre,idenvio,nombre,demora,descripcion,tarifa,estado  
FROM envios 
WHERE estado>0 ORDER BY nombre DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MIN` es una función de agregación entonces debería ir acompañada de la función `GROUP BY` para que agrupe los resultados; de tu query deberías agregarlo al final de este modo

```
SELECT MIN(idenvio),nombre,idenvio,nombre,demora,descripcion,tarifa,estado  
FROM envios 
WHERE estado>0
GROUP BY(idenvio);
```

Si observas en el `GROUP BY` uso la columna `idenvio` pues es esta la que estoy trabajando con la función `MIN` y la que me interesa mostrar el valor mínimo.

Por otro lado si la idea es mostrar el valor de `idenvio`mínimo creo que la línea de `ORDER BY....` se puede quitar y solo dejarla como te muestro

También deberías considerar el `WHERE` puesto que si no tienes mas que un valor > a 0 entonces solo mostrará 1 registro